# When browsing a site like Reddit through Tor, what would the admins see when trying to check your IP address?

Tags: networking, proxy, administrator, privacy, tor

In terms of what people tracking your IP address see, is it the same as a proxy? It just looks like you’re surfing from somewhere else in the world? Like, what exactly is meant by “surf anonymously?” Even if they can’t see your real IP address, would they be able to tell you're hiding your it? Would they know you’re using Tor specicially?

Comment: From here:  https://whatismyipaddress.com/tor  Fact is, someone with limited technical skills can "track" your IP address to a general location, such as the city where you live. (Look at our Trace Email Analyzer.) They cannot pinpoint your address or figure out who you are, but if you gave them your name or city in an email or correspondence, someone could guess or get close to figuring out where you are.

Comment: So Tor is basically pointless then?

Comment: Yes. If someone wants to find you, and have the equipment and skills, they will find you.

Comment: You should also think about this [heuristically](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/heuristically): Let’s say you are posting hyperlocal content on a hyperlocal website. Let’s say that town or city is small. And you are the only one consistently using TOR to connect to said website. And someone else know you use TOR. Guess what? You might be busted without leaking IP addresses.

Comment: If you use a private VPN+Tor, it will prevent even Tor itself from knowing where you are connecting from.  The VPN will also prevent your ISP from knowing that you are using Tor.  Still.. read the @JakeGould warning.. we all leave breadcrumbs of some sort sooner or later.

Comment: That makes no sense, since the whole point of something like Tor is to prevent users with the equipment and skills from finding you.

Comment: @KlaytonForbes: “…the whole point of something like Tor is to prevent users with the equipment and skills from finding you.” Yes, you can be found in some situations. If you live in a major city what you can do is use different Wi-Fi hotspots and connect to TOR to lessen your footprints. But what I am saying is if you live in a small town, nobody needs “equipment and skills” too really track you down. You are simply thinking of TOR as a magic cloak… And it is in many ways… But if you are the only one in the town that has or knows how to use such a cloak, guess what? You will be on a shortlist.

Comment: PS: Read this to understand things better… https://protonvpn.com/blog/is-tor-safe/

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how clever they are. Tor (and Tor Browser) is pretty good about not leaking your IP address and disable some common ways to get around that (WebRTC being one of them), but it's always possible to get served some kind of code that causes your IP to become visible.

The average internet forum administrator? Not bloody likely.

A government? More likely, since they have the ability to analyze broad swathes of the internet's traffic at once, but [even the NSA is on record as saying that Tor is a pain in the ass for them.](https://edwardsnowden.com/docs/doc/tor-stinks-presentation.pdf).

Anyone looking at where you connect from will see the IP address of the exit node you're using, just like any other proxy. Tor's "magic" is that the intermediaries between you and the exit are randomized and not controlled by the people running those nodes.

> Even if they can’t see your real IP address, would they be able to tell you're hiding your it? Would they know you’re using Tor specicially?

Yes. [The list of Tor exit nodes is public](https://www.bigdatacloud.com/insights/tor-exit-nodes). Many sites pre-emptively ban them since they are often used by bad actors.

---

However, as the comments to your question mentioned, there are ways to identify people that are not their IP address. The IP is just one of the simplest, since it leads to your account at your ISP. Tor is not magic, it's a tool, and you can easily screw yourself if you're not careful with it.